# Парсинг датафрейма с сайта ЦБ

Tags: python, парсер, pandas

Нужно взять данные из архива ЦБ (https://www.cbr.ru/archive/db/baseexchinfo/) по Биржевой информации рынка ГКО-ОФЗ
Проблема в том, что данные нельзя скачать csv, да к тому же их представление тоже плохо подходит для обработки.
Есть ли способ запихнуть их в таблицу пандас так, чтобы кроме тех столбцов, которые уже есть в таблице, появился еще столбец с названием ОФЗ?
И хотелось бы понять как это делается, какие есть методики?

ОФЗ - это облигация федерального займа
Сейчас таблица имеет следующий вид:
заголовки таблицы
Название бумаги (например, RU000A0JR0X1 (Номинал-1000 руб.)) и дальше информация по заголовкам таблицы
А хотелось бы, чтобы то название бумаги, которое стоит перед данными перешло в отдельный столбец и дублировалось для каждой строки таблицы, которая описывает данную бумагу за определенную дату.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, тут всё просто:

```py
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.cbr.ru/archive/db/baseexchinfo/'

df = pd.read_html(io=url)[0]
df["ОФЗ"] = None

print(df)
```

Метод `read_html` предназначен для конвертации всех `<table>` на странице `<html>` в отдельный `DaraFrame` объект. Почитав официальную документацию, я выяснил, что метод всегда будет возвращать `list` датафреймов пандас, даже если он всего один, как в нашем случае. Именно поэтому мы добавляем срез `[0]`

Следущей строкой мы добавляем новую колонку, со значениями `None`, т.к. вы не сказали, что там должно быть.

Comment: Дело в том, что сейчас в таблице, которую можно открыть по ссылке (https://www.cbr.ru/archive/db/baseexchinfo/) каждый новый массив строк, описывающий данные по конкретной облигации за разные даты, начинается с наименования этой облигации, которая занимает всю строку таблицы. Мне нужно, чтобы это наименование дублировалось для каждой даты в созданном столбце.

Comment: @АлександрГордеев понял, сейчас буду искать решение)